# longtabu, column width

Tags: longtable, columns, width, tabu

having an issue with longtabu and setting columns to a percentage of the table width. I've achieved what i want with tabularx:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.7\hsize}X} % 70% of table width
    \hline 
    \textbf{Time End of Step} & 
    \textbf{Step} & 
    \textbf{Event} &
    \textbf{Description} 
    \\ \hline 
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

then i try with tabu:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.1\hsize}X
    >{\hsize=.7\hsize}X} % 70% of table width
    \hline \hline
    \textbf{Time End of Step} & 
    \textbf{Step} & 
    \textbf{Event} &
    \textbf{Description} 
    \\ \hline \hline \hline \hline
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

So this produces an error, saying dimension too large. Anyone know how to use this hsize in longtabu? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

docs for http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf are found here. after reviewing them. ive come up with a solution.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {
    X[1,c]
    X[1,c]
    X[1,c]
    X[10,l]}
    \hline \hline
    \textbf{Time End of Step} & 
    \textbf{Step} & 
    \textbf{Event} &
    \textbf{Description} 
    \\ \hline \hline \hline \hline
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
    12:18:52 & 1 & 1 & this is a description for the event \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

So this is not exactly percentages but it will be good enough for what im working on. X[1,c] means its coefficient is 1 and its alignment is center. So in my above the coefficients add up to 13. so the first column will be 1/13 (7.6%) of the total table width. where as the last column will be 10/13 (76%).

Comment: I receieve the following error when I run the code above with pdflatex: 
```./mwe.tex:20: Dimension too large.
<recently read> \tabucolX 
                          
l.20 \end{longtabu}
                   
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.```

I have not figured out yet what caused the difference (I'm no latex expert though)