# New to LaTeX and need help with a table for my Lesson Plan

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

I am new to LaTeX and I decided to use it for my Lesson Plans. I have created a table for my lesson planning. But I am struggling to have it aligned properly and to have it fill the whole page in landscape mode. As far as I understand, tabularx or tabulary would be the proper way to create a table. But I was not able to translate my table into tabularx or tabulary. Any help would be much appreciated. The table should basically look like the one in the picture. My goal is to have a template lesson plan, which I can fill out when needed. Therefore, I wanted the table to have fixed length and width in each column and row so that all my lesson plans are uniform. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|llll|ll|c|c|l|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Name:\\ Lerngruppe:\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Max Mustermann\\ 5B\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Datum:\\ Zeit:\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}08.05.2018\\ 12:25 - 13:10\end{tabular} & Stundenthema: & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
Stundenziel: & \multicolumn{8}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Phasen} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Inhaltliche Schwerpunkte/ Operatoren} & Sozialform & Medien & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Intention (Lernziele o.Ä)} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Einstieg/\\ Problemaufw.\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(5')} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} &  &  &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Erarbeitung}} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(10')} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} &  &  &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Präsentation/\\ Sicherung\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(15')} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} &  &  &  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Transfer}} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{XY} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{XY}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(15')} & \multicolumn{5}{l|}{} &  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Hausaufgaben zur Stunde:} & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Hausaufgaben zur nächsten Stunde:} & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-\\ piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}  

\end{document}]
```

[image: Lesson Plan - Table]

**EDIT:**

Thanks to *Das Geek*. I was able to create a lesson plan by using *Das_Geek*s solution. I guess, it is not the most elegant solution, but it works. Especially, for someone like me who has started with LaTex just one week ago without any prior programming knowledge and whatsoever. However, some vertical lines of the table are not consistent. Is there any way to fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\newcommand{\loremi}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{flushleft}
\section{Geplanter Stundenverlauf}
\end{flushleft}
\centering\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
\begin{tabulary}{24cm}{|LL|LL|LL|LL|LL|} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Name:} & \multirow{2}{*}{John Doe} & \multirow{2}{*}{Datum:} & \multirow{2}{*}{08.05.2019} & \multirow{4}{*}{Studenthema:} & \multirow{4}{13cm}{\lorem}\\
    &&&&&\\
    \multirow{2}{*}{Lerngruppe:} & \multirow {2}{*}{5B} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeit:} & \multirow{2}{*}{12:25 - 13:10} & &\\
    &&&&&\\
    \hline
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tabulary}{24cm}{|LL|}
\multirow{2}{*}{Stundenziel:} & \multirow{2}{22cm}{\lorem}\\
&\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tabulary}{24cm}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
\multirow{1}{2cm}{\centering PHASEN} & \multirow{1}{9cm}{\centering INHALTLICHE SCHWERPUNKTE/OPERATOREN} & \multirow{1}{2,5cm}{\centering SOZIALFORM} & \multirow{1}{1,5cm}{\centering MEDIEN} & \multirow{1}{7cm}{\centering INTENTION LERNZIEL O.Ä}\\
\hline
&\\
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\textbf{Einstieg}\\ (10')} & \multirow{2}{9cm}{\loremi} & \multirow{2}{2,5cm}{\centering UG} & \multirow{2}{1,5cm}{\centering Foto} & \multirow{2}{7cm}{\loremi}\\\
&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
\hline
&\\
\multirow{2}{2cm}{\textbf{Erarbei- \\tung I}\\ (10')} & \multirow{2}{9cm}{\loremi} & \multirow{2}{2,5cm}{\centering UG} & \multirow{2}{1,5cm}{\centering Foto} & \multirow{2}{7cm}{\loremi}\\\
&&&\\
&&&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tabulary}{24cm}{|LL|}
\multirow{2}{*}{Hausaufgaben zur Stunde:} & \multirow{2}{19cm}{\loremi}\\
&\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tabulary}{24cm}{|LL|}
\multirow{2}{*}{Hausaufgaben zur nächsten Stunde:} & \multirow{2}{18cm}{\loremi}\\
&\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Final Table]

**Edit2**
Thanks to *Sveinung*. This was the best working solution for me. It is very clean and it works like a charm in my documents. Both solutions helped me to understand LaTeX better.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the picture you mentioned?

Comment: Done! Image is now included.

Comment: Edited my comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another possible solution, after fine tuning and tweeking. All columns are set in relation of the `\columnwidth`, so it will survive a change from `letter` to `A4`. The text with in the cells relate to the width of individual table column. I have set all tables in relation to each other, i.e. base width is 1/15-column width, and the other columns are 2/15 and 4/15 (before all the `\multicolumns`. Still it is lot of room for improvement. The last column is too narrow compared to your example. It is easy to fix, but some coding work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape, array, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newlength{\bcw} % basis column (Medien) 1/15 columnwidth - tabcolsep
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\rule{0pt}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}}m{0pt}@{}}    
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\arraybackslash}p{2\bcw}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\arraybackslash}p{4\bcw}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2\bcw}}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\bcw}}

\newcommand{\Imc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mci}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{p{2\bcw}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcI}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcII}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|m{4\bcw+2\tabcolsep}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcV}[1]{\multicolumn{5}{m{9\bcw+6\tabcolsep}|}{#1}}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\bcw}{((\columnwidth) / 15) - \tabcolsep} 
\centering
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}\\[1ex] % Chicking the width of the table
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|P|P|P|P|S|s|B|L}

\hline
\mcI{Name:} 
& Max Mustermann
&\mci{Datum:}
&08.05.2018
&\mci{Stundenthema:}
&\multicolumn{2}{p{5\bcw}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit}
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\mcI{Lerngruppe:}
&5B
&\mci{Zeit:}
&12:25 -- 13:10
&\mci{}
&\multicolumn{2}{p{5\bcw}|}{}
&
\\
\hline
\mcI{Stundenziel: }
&\multicolumn{6}{>{\raggedright}m{13\bcw+10\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. }

&\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\hline
\mcc{Phasen}
&\multicolumn{3}{>{\centering}p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{Inhaltliche Schwerpunkte/ Operatoren}
&\Imc{Sozialform}
&\Imc{Medien}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Intention (Lernziele o.Ä)}
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\hline
&
\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{}
&&
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\textbf{Einstieg/\newline Problemaufw.}
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
&XY
&XY
&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
(5’)
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{}
&&&
&
\\
\textbf{Erarbeitung}
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
&XY
&XY
&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
(10’)
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{}
&&&&
\\
\textbf{Präsentation}
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
&XY
&XY
&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
(15’)
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{}
&&&&
\\
\textbf{Transfer}
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
&XY
&XY
&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
&\rule{0pt}{2.2\normalbaselineskip}
\\
(15’)
&\multicolumn{3}{p{6\bcw+2\tabcolsep}|}{}
&&&&
\\
\hline
\mcII{Hausaufgabe zur Stunden:}
&\mcV{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}
&\rule{0pt}{3.3\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\hline
\mcII{Hausaufgabe zur näcsten Stunden:}
&\mcV{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. }
&\rule{0pt}{3.3\normalbaselineskip}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for all the fine tuning. You might have noticed the slichtly thicker vertical lines around `Sozialform` and `Medien`. To remove them, you will have to define another additional column for example as follows: `\newcommand{\mcca}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}`

Comment: @leandriis I noticed that, but did not take the time to fix it. I will have a further look later. It is probably better ways to construct this tabular, using other packages. LaTeX is to complex to have dynamically updated tabulars, unless you write a front-end to input the variable text. But then you need to write a package.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have already worked with Das_Geeks solution. But I will also try out your solution in order to learn more!

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution. +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is indeed a much cleaner solution. It works like a charm.

Comment: @Gino28 I am glad you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide a solution that covers the first section of your table, and leave the remaining rows as an exercise for the reader (forgive me, teacher habits ;) ).

### First, to address your column width issue.

In this case, where you have a large amount of text, the [`tabulary`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabulary_package) package seems to fit the best. It allows shorter columns to be resized to their natural length, while trying its best to not go past the total width you specify. This will be enough to keep the bounds of your table inside the page.

### Next, to address your overflow issue

You use `multirow` several times in your example. However, you are using the `*` specifier; this allows the text to overflow outside the column walls. So for columns with lots of content, you must replace the `*` with a length that forces text to wrap at that length.

There is some more caution to be had when using `multirow`: you can't think of it as filling *a number of rows* (go figure). Rather, you have to think of it as replacing *a number of lines of text*. This is why in my example below I use four rows for the lorem ipsum. While specifying column width according to the paragraph above is sufficient to make your text wrap, you have to adjust your `multirow` specification in order to have the cell's borders span the entire height of the text.

### Without further ado...

The example! As mentioned earlier, I only wrote enough to cover the first section of your desired table. Hopefully this was enough to help guide the rest of your design. Good luck with your lesson plans!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabulary}{1.25\textwidth}{|LL|LL|LL|} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Name:} & \multirow{2}{*}{Max Mustermann} & \multirow{2}{*}{Datum:} & \multirow{2}{*}{08.05.2019} & \multirow{4}{*}{Studenthema:} & \multirow{4}{12cm}{\lorem}\\
    &&&&&\\
    \multirow{2}{*}{Lerngruppe:} & \multirow{2}{*}{5B} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeit:} & \multirow{2}{*}{12:25 - 13:10} & &\\
    &&&&&\\
    \hline

\end{tabulary}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

### The result:

[image: Compilation result]

Comment: What's the purpose of using `longtabu` if you a) only use fixed width `p` type columns and b) have a table that aparently will only need one page? Wouldn't a simple `tabular` be sufficient for the solution you propose?

Comment: Yes, it will. I use `longtabu` to in the eventuality that OP copy-pastes my example, but decides to use the column width specification method [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153072/188049). I'll add that reason to my answer.

Comment: Although I personally like the idea of the `tabu` package (easily declare and use flexible width columns of different widths and different alignments) you might want to be careful using this package as there are quite some unexpected results that might occur using this package. Personally, I'd recomment `tabularx` instead.

Comment: tabu is depreciated, buggy and not compatible with other packages. Do not use it. It was very promising, but unfortunately, the developer did not finish it (to complicated).

Comment: Edited answer to exclusively reference the `tabulary` package.

Comment: Edited my original post. Hope for some additional recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

A totally different approach is to use the eminent, but little known, package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) to build the tabular. Actually, [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) is more or less tailor made to build this type of tabulars, because you build the tabular cell by cell. The documentation is rudimentary and a little bit difficult to understand. In particular, the spanning commands are difficult to understand, but when you understand them, they are logically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cals, pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    % Shortcuts
\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{calstable}[c]
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*4\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*4\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*3\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*3\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*4\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*2\relax}
                  {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/30*10\relax}
                  {0pt}
        }
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}

%
\brow
        \rb\alignL \cell{Name:\vfill Lerngruppe:}\rb
        \alignL \cell{Max Mustermann\vfill 5B}
        \rb\alignL \cell{Datum:\vfill Zeit:}\rb
        \alignL \cell{08-05-2019\vfill 12:25 -- 13:10}
        \rb\alignC \cell{\vfil Stundenthema:}\rb
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{3.3\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \rb\alignL \cell{\vfil Stundenziel:}\rb
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \\ consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \alignC \cell{\vfil Phasen}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Inhaltliche Schwerpunkte/ Operatoren}
        \alignC \cell{\vfil Sozialform}
        \alignC \cell{\vfil Medien}
        \alignC \cell{\vfil Intention (Lernziele o.Ä)}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \bb\alignC \cell{}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{}
        \alignC \cell{}
        \alignC \cell{}
        \alignC \cell{}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{1.1\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \alignL\cell{\textbf{Einstieg/\\ Problemaufw.}\vfil(5’)}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignL\cell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \alignL\cell{\textbf{Erarbeitung}\vfil(10’)}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignL\cell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \alignL\cell{\textbf{Präsentation}\vfil(15’)}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignL\cell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \bb\cell{\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \alignL\cell{\textbf{Transfer}\vfil(15’)}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignC \cell{XY}
        \alignL\cell{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{4.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Hausaufgabe zur Stunde:}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{3.85\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
    %
\brow
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Hausaufgabe zur nächten Stunde:}
        \nc{ltb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{tb}
        \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\vfil Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauri}
        \cell{\rule{0pt}{3.85\normalbaselineskip}}
\erow
\makeatother
\end{calstable}\par

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]